# Disable Camera on Android using ADB Shell

Tags: camera, adb

I am using 4.1 JB Rooted Device & want to completely disable Camera on my mobile as it is not allowed at my work place. Currently I am using 'Disable Camera device' app but one can easily Enable camera using this app.

I am looking for a way where without a PC & connecting through ADB one should not be able to Enable camera. Technicians at our workplace should also not be able to enable the camera.

---

I have got the following codes from one of the Camera Disabled app... How to use them?

Support Shell command line operation

```
> adb shell
$ am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n jp.ne.neko.freewing.DisableCameraDevice/.CameraDeviceDisable
$ am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n jp.ne.neko.freewing.DisableCameraDevice/.CameraDeviceEnable
```

Comment: The only true way of disabling the camera is to recompile the kernel minus camera drivers...

Comment: BTW what is the device in question?

Comment: Is it resolved ? How ?